# I want to build a new ISO based on official Ubuntu 18.04 ISO, plus some propietary software. What do I have to open-source to comply with GPL2?

Tags: licensing, gpl-2, proprietary-code, redistribution, intellectual-property

What if I do not own the proprietary software but I have been given permission to distribute it (will being able to open-source the build automation help? This would mean only someone with the correct connection to the proprietary software's VPN would be able to run the automation correctly)?

If I do own the proprietary software, do I have to open-source it under GPL2 license?

If I include an open-source script that pulls in closed-source content upon initial install, am I covered?

How did Nvidia and Ubuntu get it right to [include proprietary drivers in the Ubuntu ISO?](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-19.10-NVIDIA-On-ISO)

Struggling to know what is legal. I take it very seriously and am attempting to avoid violation.

Comment: Please see [GPL FAQ - MereAggregation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#MereAggregation). For example, including a proprietary program in a distribution of programs, some of which are open source, and others which are not, is "mere aggregation". The proprietary driver question is a stickier issue though; probably it has been discussed before here and elsewhere. If that is your question (proprietary driver in the Linux kernel), post it separately or ideally search the site for that issue.

Comment: Since I posted this question I read that only GNU packages and Linux Kernel are various licenses (many GPL2/3). Ubuntu as the collection is not licensed by GPL*

Comment: @Brandin you want to write that up as an answer?